# How to add escape character in string?

Tags: swift

```
editedDate = `"16/11/2016 10:58:11"`
```

I want to send above string to server with escape character.

```
let revisedText = editedDate.replacingOccurrences(of: "/", with: "\\/")
```

Still i get value as

```
"16\\/11\\/2016 10:58:11"
```

I want

```
"16\/11\/2016 10:58:11"
```

Comment: Why are there backticks?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the value is correct. The console prints out the output with an additional backslash.

Answer (score 1):

The value is actually correct. Here is the output of the playground when printing the variable:

[image: playground]

**However**, you may just have seen the value in the sidebar if you are using playground or in LLDB:

[image: playground]

In that way, you can see the escape character is shown (`\`). Actually, it's not there. You can safely send the string to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. Use `print` to show the modified string on console. Debugger or REPL will escape the output, too, e.g. `lldb`:

```
(lldb) po editedDate.replacingOccurrences(of: "/", with: "\\/")
"16\\/11\\/2016 10:58:11"
(lldb) p print(editedDate.replacingOccurrences(of: "/", with: "\\/"))
16\/11\/2016 10:58:11
```